# Google cloud service account on VM is being denied permission to push to Artifact Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-artifact-registry

I am on a Google Compute VM and am trying to to push a container from there to the artifact registry. I'm the owner/admin of the project.

when I run docker push ... I get the error

```
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/locations/<MY_LOCATION>/repositories/<MY_REPOSITORY>" (or it may not exist)
```

running `gcloud auth list` shows a service account `*****-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

running `gcloud auth configure-docker` shows what seems like docker being configured

```
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "<MY_LOCATION>-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}
```

Lastly, running `gcloud artifacts docker images list <MY_REPOSITORY>`
*does* return a list current artifacts, so obviously the account has read permissions.

Edit: I've tried a couple of more things. I've gone to the VM's page and enabled `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`, rebooted the VM, and still blocked. I even tried to use my project owner credentials (which work fine outside of the VM) by setting up google auth login while on the VM. Still blocked.

I've set the roles to be read/write for the service account, I've restarted my VM, but nothing is working. Please help!

SOLVED:
The steps needed were

1. Go to the VM instance on Google compute and ensure that `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` is selected
2. Go to IAM and set permissions on Artifact Registry to write (read implicity included). Or on the cli `cloud compute instances set-service-account <YOUR_INSTANCE> --scopes=cloud-platform,storage-rw`
3. Inside of the VM, run `gcloud auth configure-docker <YOUR_LOCATION>`. The last part is crucial. It seems like this command still defaults to gcr and hasn't been updated for the Artifact registry yet.

Comment: You have to change the OAuth scope of your Compute Engine or use a custom service account.

Comment: can you be more specific? I've tried running `gcloud compute instances set-service-account INSTANCE --scopes=cloud-platform,storage-ro` according to this page https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#compute but still no luck

Comment: Can you try to configure credentials with **sudo gcloud auth configure-docker**, as with sudo it looks for credentials in **/root/.docker/config.json** rather than the default path used with Docker security group. Refer to the Quickstart in [doc1](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/store-docker-container-images) very helpful for this process along with [doc2](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#before_you_begin), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I didn't install docker in rootless mode so I've been using sudo this whole time already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is to understand authorization while running in Compute Engine. There are two authorization methods: Service Account and ADC (Application Default Credentials).

By default, a service account is assigned to each Compute Engine instance. In your case, the VM has been assigned `*****-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

Additionally, compute engine has `Access Scopes`. This feature will limit the permissions assigned to the service account. VM Access Scopes do NOT grant permissions. These are often confused with `OAuth Access Scopes`. They are similar but used for different purposes.

Go to the Google Cloud Console, edit the VM, and select `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`. That selection does not mean the VM can now access everything. It actually means that the service account is no longer restricted and permissions are now managed by IAM roles assigned to the service account.

Next, add the required IAM role to the service account so that you can upload to Artifact Registry. The list of IAM Roles is [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles). The permission required is `artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts`. A good role to use in this case is `Artifact Registry Writer` (roles/artifactregistry.writer). More details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#artifact-registry-roles).

At the beginning of this answer, notice the authorization method ADC (Application Default Credentials). ADC is a method of searching for credentials. When running on Compute Engine, Google Cloud tools and SDK libraries will search for credentials unless directly specified. The CLI command `gcloud auth application-default login` [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) allows you to set up credentials to use instead of the Compute Engine service account. ADC will select the credentials stored by the CLI before the credentials created by the service account. Which one to use (VM service account or application default credentials) is both a convenience feature and a security issue. By only using service account credentials, you can lock down a VM. If you use `gcloud auth ..` with a user that has powerful privileges, you have bypassed the security features of the service account.

If you chose to use ADC, then execute this command when finished:

`gcloud auth application-default revoke`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I didn't know about that additional VM constraint! I changed the instance settings to `Allow Full Access to Cloud APIs` and have checked (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=) that the IAM role `Artifact Registry Writer` is assigned to the proper default compute service account. But, I'm still blocked with the same error.

Comment: This is also weird; I tried to override, and on the VM setup `gcloud auth login` as the project owner using my personal credentials. Ran gcloud auth list and it shows I'm logged in. Still blocked. The same command on my personal computer works just fine though.

Comment: @JKJK - Rerun the command `gcloud auth configure-docker <MY_LOCATION>-docker.pkg.dev`.

Comment: still blocked. I also removed the previous config at /root/.docker/config.json before running just to be sure

Comment: @JKIK Then there is something else happening on your VM instance (something is not configured as you believe).

Comment: Hey John I ended up solving it, see my above update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, those steps in your edit are part of my answer plus comments. Note: don't do this: --`scopes=cloud-platform,storage-rw` Only set `--scopes=cloud-platform`.

Comment: One difference between my answer and your edit. The usage of `sudo`. That means you are switching identities. That affects where credential files are expected to be. That is another reason why it is important to include exactly what you are doing in your post. In most cases you should never, let me repeat, never use `sudo` when working with credentials.

Comment: please explain why I don't want storage-rw, if anything I think it should be the oppposite that I don't want cloud-platform: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20push%20images%2C%20the%20VM%20instance%20service%20account%20must%20have%20the%20storage%2Drw%20scope

Comment: I answered that in my post. Using a VM's `Access Scopes` is a legacy authorization method that existed before Google Cloud IAM. Those scopes do not grant permission - the service account must already have that permission. My recommendation is to use `cloud-platform` and control access via Google Cloud IAM. The technical reason you do not want to specify `storage-rw` is that `cloud-platform` already has that `scope`.

Comment: Google Cloud IAM permissions are far more extensive that the legacy scopes method. Some/most permissions cannot be managed via a VM's Access Scopes.

Comment: In essence, a VM's Access Scopes were (past tense) for USER identities (OAuth). For service accounts, you should be using Google Cloud IAM and IAM Roles for access control.